# Google Play leaderboards for AIR app/game?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have made a game in Actionscript 3 and I made it for android. Now I want scores, but can't find any good tutorial. Half tutorials are for local highscores (with shared object and I don't need that) and other half is in as2 or as1, everyone had been using mochi leaderboards but they closed recently. I found out about google play leaderboards, and I saw milkman has an extension for it, but I wouldn't pay 50$ if I don't have to, is there a way I can use google leaderboards without milkman on air? Also on adobe forum, there is a tutorial, but with milkman :\

Answer (score 0):

Try this ANE : https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services. Haven't really used it (I use milkman)...but it's free by the looks of it.